# Dynamically build a selection list from a list with an unknown number of members

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic

What I am trying to do is create a silevrlight popup that displays images to a user and lets them select a radio control underneath to determine which option they have selected.  I have an object like this:

```
 public class ConfigImage
{
    public int ConfigID { get; set; }
    public string ConfigName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

The code returns a list of ConfigImage with an unknown number of members.  I am trying to use a grid to display the images to the user, so I dynamically add columns based on the number of members in the list.  I expect anywhere from 2-5 members to be in the list.  What I am having the problem with is trying to dynamically add the image and radio controls.  I cannot seem to find an example anywhere of this.  I tried to add controls using code such as this:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new Label);
```

but then have no idea how to set properties on the new Label control.  I should know this, but I am drawing blank and cannot seem to find an example of it.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to add the controls in code, you will need to have a reference to the object in order to set properties on it:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Content = "text";
label.Width = 10;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(label);
```

Alternatively, you can use initializers:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new Label()
{
    Content = "text",
    Width = 10
});
```

As BrokenGlass said, you can probably do this completely in xaml, though.

**Edit:** To illustrate the xaml-only approach using BrokenGlass's suggestion of ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ConfigImagesItemsControl" ItemsSource="MyConfigImagesList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ConfigName}" GroupName="ConfigImagesGroup" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use any of the list based UI elements in Silverlight - those would allow you to data bind to an observable collection that you can update at runtime, simplest one would be [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) - what markup you use for each item in the collection you can completely control in XAML.